# Nested array filtering, is there a more elegant way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I'm trying to filter a nested structure, based on a search string.

If the search string is matched in an item, then I want to keep that item in the structure, along with its parents.

If the search string is not found, and the item has no children, it can be discounted.

I've got some code working which uses a recursive array filter to check the children of each item:

```js
const data = {
  id: '0.1',
  children: [
    {
      children: [],
      id: '1.1'
    },
    {
      id: '1.2',
      children: [
        {
          children: [],
          id: '2.1'
        },
        {
          id: '2.2',
          children: [
            {
              id: '3.1',
              children: []
            },
            {
              id: '3.2',
              children: []
            },
            {
              id: '3.3',
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          children: [],
          id: '2.3'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};


const searchString = '3.3';

const filterChildren = (item) => {
  if (item.children.length) {
    item.children = item.children.filter(filterChildren);
    return item.children.length;
  }
  return item.id.includes(searchString);
};


data.children = data.children.filter(filterChildren);

console.log(data);

/*This outputs:
{
  "id": "0.1",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "1.2",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "2.2",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "3.3",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}*/
```

I'm concerned that if my data structure becomes massive, this won't be very efficient.

Can this be achieved in a 'nicer' way, that limits the amount of looping going on? I'm thinking probably using a reducer/transducer or something similarly exciting :)

Comment: you are mutating the data. is it intended?

Comment: Recursion is the only way to iterate at arbitrary nesting level.

Comment: @hindmost You've misspelled "the simplest way" as "_the only way_" ; ).

Comment: @Teemu You can suggest other way (without recursion)?

Comment: @hindmost nested loops are not actually recursive, and the task can be done by using nested loops too.

Comment: I meant _arbitrary_ (unknown) nesting level

Comment: @hindmost Yes, that's what I mean too.

Comment: @NinaScholz In my actual implementation I've created a deep copy of the data so that it can be mutated. If there's a solution which builds a new structure as it goes along that would be preferable

Comment: @hindmost I believe you could always use a loop and a stack to replace the recursive structure.

Comment: @Cat It seems that we talk about the same thing in different terms. AFAIU loop with call stack is effectively the same as recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nonmutating version with a search for a child.

```js
function find(array, id) {
    var child,
        result = array.find(o => o.id === id || (child = find(o.children, id)));

    return child
        ? Object.assign({}, result, { children: [child] })
        : result;            
}

const
    data = { id: '0.1', children: [{ children: [], id: '1.1' }, { id: '1.2', children: [{ children: [], id: '2.1' }, { id: '2.2', children: [{ id: '3.1', children: [] }, { id: '3.2', children: [] }, { id: '3.3', children: [] }] }, { children: [], id: '2.3' }] }] },
    searchString = '3.3',
    result = find([data], searchString);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```